# Cannot reshape array of size 1980416 to (32,32)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
test = np.arange(1980416).reshape((32,32))
```

This gives an ValueError: cannot reshape to some shape. This is strange though, as 32 * 32 = 1024, and 1980416 / 1024 is an integer. Any other methods to reshape the array to 32x32 without np.reshape()?

Comment: `reshape` requires the same number of element (product of the dimensions) both before and after.  It does not drop or add elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `-1` for the first axis in the reshape, that way the amount of `32` by `32` arrays will be inferred:

```
test.reshape(-1,32,32)
```

---

```
test = np.arange(1980416)
print(test.reshape(-1,32,32,).shape)
# (1934, 32, 32)
```